# How to check if application can connect to API server or not

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I'm writing an application with [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). My application retrieves data from an API.
I want to implement a common function to check if my application can connect to API server, but I don't know how to?

Can someone help me?

Comment: you should at least try to solve this alone, come back afterwards to show your efforts

Comment: What do you mean by "connect to API server"? If that server is effectively an independent system, and especially if there's a network between your application and the API server, you're almost certainly creating a function that answers a question you don't need. If the function says "yes, the API server can be connected to", but then the server disappears or the network goes down before you *act* on that answer, things will still break. You need to write code that deals with the server disappearing *anyway*, just write *that* code and abandon any attempts to pre-check availability.